# Row with thumbnail height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What can I do to this row...

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span2">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.jetstrap.com/SLgRUEHSyGwQVfG4x6ed_curso_adm.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <h3>
            Título
        </h3>
        <p>
            Ahduh eo ohae flaeh kjdkvjzvahofvh oiadfp oivahcx vhkj jknv vj v v jshvpioauhfspvus
            fvga icvg acjkb jahbcjkhabs vhafs avicx jk b iuhiuah i cioua iu uiashuioas
            diouvhas iusu agyq gqh rgnmwetg brkb hhvwi uvqiuhuie veiu
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span3" style="display: none;">
        <h3>
            Span 4
        </h3>
        <p>
            Content
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="span3" style="display: none;">
        <h3>
            Span 3
        </h3>
        <p>
            Content here
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

...stay with the thumbnail height? When I resize the window, the image gets a margin at bottom.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cbacelar/Fzfb6/

Thanks.

Comment: if the row height remained the same height as the image then it wouldn't be responsive and a user would need to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the `<p>` tag inside the row has a `margin-bottom` of 10px. Remove that and you'll see the space below the image disappear.